# Term for statements with vacuous weakest precondition

Tags: preconditions, formal-methods, hoare-logic

It seems like the class of statement, postcondition pairs `(S, R)` such that the weakest precondition `wp(S, R)` is `true` is a particularly interesting one (being in some sense “always” true).

Is there a term for this set or property?